# Matplotlib imshow remove axis but keep axis labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to make an array of matrix plots in python. Something along these lines

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(16, 12))
for i in range(3):
    ax[i][0].set_ylabel(str(i))
    for j in range(4):
        ax[0][j].set_title(str(j))
        ax[i][j].imshow(np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 50)))
        #ax[i][j].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

I get the following (Call it Plot 1)

[image]

Now I would like to remove the ticks and the black box on which the ticks sit. I uncomment the line `ax[i][j].axis('off')` and get the following (call it Plot 2)

[image]

Now the problem is that my y-labels have disappeared! How do I get exactly the same figure as in the 2nd example, but with y-labels as in 1st example?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(16, 12))
for i in range(3):
    ax[i][0].set_ylabel(str(i))
    for j in range(4):
        ax[0][j].set_title(str(j))
        ax[i][j].imshow(np.random.normal(0, 1, (50, 50)))
        ax[i][j].get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
        ax[i][j].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
        for spine in ax[i, j].spines.values():
            spine.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]